# garch half-life in R 3.1.1 (and failed rugarch install)

Tags: r, time-series

I am running ubuntu 14.10, late beta, up-to-date.

I would like to try a garch model in R 3.1.1.  specifically, an MA(1) or ARMA(1,1) with a volatility component.

first, I need to install a garch package.  (arima seems part of default R, but not garima.)  a well-recommended package among others for garch is guarch.

```
> install.packages("ruguarch")
...
ERROR: dependency 'ks' is not available for package 'rugarch'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rugarch'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpUBvb9C/downloaded_packages'
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("rugarch") :
  installation of package 'rgl' had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("rugarch") :
  installation of package 'ks' had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("rugarch") :
  installation of package 'rugarch' had non-zero exit status
```

on the solo ks install,

```
> install.packages("ks")
...
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
```

of course, even if I get this to work, it will only be step 1.  then I need to find a package that can give me a half-life.  (I am not a TS expert or an R expert, and perhaps not really an expert on anything.  I hope these questions are not obscure.)  I must admit that I only know the half-life of an AR1, not the half-life of an MA1, much less that of a GARIMA(?,1,0,1).

Answer (score 3):

A few quick points:

1. You have typos in your question. It is `rugarch`, not `guarch`
2. `rugarch` by Alexios is a very powerful, and very demanding package. It relies on a (large) number of other packages.  Your installation failed, among other things, because you did not have as many preconditions met as you could have.
3. With that, for starters do a `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpparmadillo r-cran-rgl`. Particularly `rgl` is tricky as you need to realize that you need OpenGL headers, so why not take the binary package.  Ditto for RcppArmadillo which will also get you Rcpp.
4. Once you do that, chances are that the installation succeeds. I just tested in a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04, and it was no problem.  If things fail, examine build failures closely.

For reference, below is the installation on a system which already had a number of other packages installed, including Rcpp and rgl, but which still needed a large number for rugarch.  This is eunning inside a Docker container, henec the root user and funky hostname. `install.r` is a helper script from the littler package.

```
root@96097d7112b1:/# install.r rugarch
install.r rugarch
also installing the dependencies 'truncnorm', 'misc3d', 'multicool', 'DistributionUtils', 'GeneralizedHyperbolic', 'RUnit', 'Rsolnp', 'nloptr', 'ks', 'numDeriv', 'spd', 'xts', 'chron', 'SkewHyperbolic', 'expm', 'RcppArmadillo'

trying URL [.... downloads omitted to keep this within 30kb limit for SO... ]  


* installing *source* package 'truncnorm' ...
** package 'truncnorm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rtruncnorm.c -o rtruncnorm.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c truncnorm.c -o truncnorm.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c zeroin.c -o zeroin.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o truncnorm.so rtruncnorm.o truncnorm.o zeroin.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/truncnorm/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (truncnorm)
* installing *source* package 'misc3d' ...
** package 'misc3d' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (misc3d)
* installing *source* package 'multicool' ...
** package 'multicool' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c multicool.cpp -o multicool.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o multicool.so multicool.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/multicool/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (multicool)
* installing *source* package 'RUnit' ...
** package 'RUnit' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RUnit)
* installing *source* package 'nloptr' ...
** package 'nloptr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: Now testing for NLopt header file.
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking nlopt.h usability... no
checking nlopt.h presence... no
checking for nlopt.h... no
configure: Need to download and build NLopt
trying URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2361992 bytes (2.3 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 2.3 Mb

configure: Starting to install library to /tmp/RtmphBrgVr/R.INSTALL2431668f0e2/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2
configure: Done installing library to /tmp/RtmphBrgVr/R.INSTALL2431668f0e2/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG     -I/tmp/RtmphBrgVr/R.INSTALL2431668f0e2/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c nloptr.c -o nloptr.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o nloptr.so dummy.o nloptr.o -lm /tmp/RtmphBrgVr/R.INSTALL2431668f0e2/nloptr/nlopt-2.4.2/lib/libnlopt_cxx.a -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/nloptr/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (nloptr)
* installing *source* package 'numDeriv' ...
** package 'numDeriv' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
   'Guide.Stex' 
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (numDeriv)
* installing *source* package 'spd' ...
** package 'spd' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Creating a generic function from function 'gpdfit' in package 'spd'
Creating a generic function from function 'spdfit' in package 'spd'
Creating a generic function from function 'pspd' in package 'spd'
Creating a generic function from function 'dspd' in package 'spd'
Creating a generic function from function 'qspd' in package 'spd'
Creating a generic function from function 'rspd' in package 'spd'
Creating a generic function for 'plot' from package 'graphics' in package 'spd'
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (spd)
* installing *source* package 'xts' ...
** package 'xts' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c add_class.c -o add_class.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c any.c -o any.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c attr.c -o attr.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c binsearch.c -o binsearch.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c coredata.c -o coredata.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c diff.c -o diff.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dimnames.c -o dimnames.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c endpoints.c -o endpoints.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c extract_col.c -o extract_col.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c isOrdered.c -o isOrdered.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c isXts.c -o isXts.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c leadingNA.c -o leadingNA.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c merge.c -o merge.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c period.max.f -o period.max.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c period.min.f -o period.min.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c period.prod.f -o period.prod.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c period.sum.f -o period.sum.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rbind.c -o rbind.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rollfun.c -o rollfun.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c runSum.c -o runSum.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c startofyear.c -o startofyear.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c subset.c -o subset.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c subset.old.c -o subset.old.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c toperiod.c -o toperiod.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c totalcols.c -o totalcols.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tryXts.c -o tryXts.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c unique.time.c -o unique.time.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o xts.so add_class.o any.o attr.o binsearch.o coredata.o diff.o dimnames.o endpoints.o extract_col.o init.o isOrdered.o isXts.o leadingNA.o merge.o period.max.o period.min.o period.prod.o period.sum.o rbind.o rollfun.o runSum.o startofyear.o subset.o subset.old.o toperiod.o totalcols.o tryXts.o unique.time.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xts/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (xts)
* installing *source* package 'chron' ...
** package 'chron' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c chron_strs.c -o chron_strs.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c unpaste.c -o unpaste.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o chron.so chron_strs.o init.o unpaste.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/chron/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (chron)
* installing *source* package 'expm' ...
** package 'expm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c R_dgebal.c -o R_dgebal.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c expm-eigen.c -o expm-eigen.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c expm.c -o expm.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c logm-eigen.c -o logm-eigen.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c matexp.f -o matexp.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c matpow.c -o matpow.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c matrexp.f -o matrexp.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c matrexpO.f -o matrexpO.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c mexp-common.f -o mexp-common.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o expm.so R_dgebal.o expm-eigen.o expm.o init.o logm-eigen.o matexp.o matpow.o matrexp.o matrexpO.o mexp-common.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/expm/libs
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (expm)
* installing *source* package 'RcppArmadillo' ...
** package 'RcppArmadillo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* checking LAPACK_LIBS: divide-and-conquer complex SVD available via system LAPACK
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RcppArmadillo)
* installing *source* package 'DistributionUtils' ...
** package 'DistributionUtils' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c IncompleteBessel.f -o IncompleteBessel.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o DistributionUtils.so IncompleteBessel.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/DistributionUtils/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (DistributionUtils)
* installing *source* package 'Rsolnp' ...
** package 'Rsolnp' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Rsolnp)
* installing *source* package 'ks' ...
** package 'ks' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c ks.c -o ks.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o ks.so ks.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ks/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
  RGL: unable to open X11 display
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : error in rgl_init
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
  RGL: unable to open X11 display
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : error in rgl_init
* DONE (ks)
* installing *source* package 'GeneralizedHyperbolic' ...
** package 'GeneralizedHyperbolic' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (GeneralizedHyperbolic)
* installing *source* package 'SkewHyperbolic' ...
** package 'SkewHyperbolic' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (SkewHyperbolic)
* installing *source* package 'rugarch' ...
** package 'rugarch' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c distributions.c -o distributions.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c filters.c -o filters.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fracdiff.c -o fracdiff.o
gfortran   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c fracimport.f -o fracimport.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c garchmodels.c -o garchmodels.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c garchsim.cpp -o garchsim.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c gig.c -o gig.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c nig.c -o nig.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-z,relro -o rugarch.so distributions.o filters.o fracdiff.o fracimport.o garchmodels.o garchsim.o gig.o nig.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rugarch/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
  RGL: unable to open X11 display
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : error in rgl_init
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchspec' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'getspec' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchfilter' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchfit' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchforecast' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchsim' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchpath' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'resume' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchroll' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchdistribution' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'ugarchboot' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'plot' from package 'graphics' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'report' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'coef' from package 'stats' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'as.data.frame' from package 'base' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'residuals' from package 'stats' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'sigma' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'nyblom' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'signbias' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'gof' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'infocriteria' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'likelihood' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'fitted' from package 'stats' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'reduce' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'quantile' from package 'stats' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'pit' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'newsimpact' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'halflife' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'persistence' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'uncvariance' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'uncmean' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'multispec' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'multifit' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'multifilter' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'multiforecast' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'fpm' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'convergence' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function for 'vcov' from package 'stats' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimaspec' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimafit' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimafilter' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimaforecast' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimasim' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimapath' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimaroll' in package 'rugarch'
Creating a generic function from function 'arfimadistribution' in package 'rugarch'
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
  RGL: unable to open X11 display
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : error in rgl_init
* DONE (rugarch)

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/downloaded_packages'
root@96097d7112b1:/#
```

Comment: hi dirk--- the in-R install-packages rugarch still did not work:

/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'rugarch.so' failed
make: *** [rugarch.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rugarch'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rugarch'

"apt-get install littler" tells me that I already had the last version.  alas, there does not seem to be an install.r script in it.

because I run 14.10, this may be at fault.  if it is, it won't be long before there are others with the same problem....

Comment: `install.r` has been in littler for several years but you need to copy it out of the examples directory.

Comment: thanks, dirk.  indeed.  I should have seen this.  I am doing a remote install.  rugarch now fails with
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
  RGL: unable to open X11 display
Warning in fun(libname, pkgname) : error in rgl_init
* DONE (rugarch)
I will try this on the GUI on Monday.  if this were a server, it might not usually run the GUI.  I figure it will work on it.

Comment: it did install the non-GUI part.  it is a *very* nice R package with a good introductory vignette.  highly recommended by a time-series novice.  and thank you, dirk.